# Cannot play video via react-player on iOS devices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-video, digital-ocean, react-player

We use DigitalOcean spaces as a storage for media files. When I try to play any uploaded video with `react-player` I only see a crossed-out play button. The problem only occurs on iOS devices both in Chrome and Safari.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTwti.png)

Here is what my component looks like

```
                <ReactPlayer
                    url="https://appname.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/username/folder_id/file_id"
                    playsInline
                    controls
                    loop
                    height="100%"
                    width="100%"
                />
```

[digital ocean preview of the video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHJmh.png)

The video was shot on iPhone's native camera via file `input` with `capture` attribute and uploaded to DigitalOcean using multipart upload.

CORS settings are set to allow all origins on DO and I do not receive any CORS error while trying to play the video

Comment: Hi Oleksandr, I'm also using react and having a problem not seeing Android recorded videos on the iOS version of the app. What is the file format of your DigitalOcean url? MP4? My iphones can only view MP4 files. Not webm.

Comment: Hello please currently having the same can you share info on how you fixed this .